# How to show separate values from appended list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to display values from appended list of items that are scraped with bs4. Currently, my code only returns a whole set of data, but I'd like to have separate values displayed from the data. Now, all I get is:

> NameError: value is not defined.

How to do it?

```
data = []

for e in soup.select('div:has(> div > a h3)'):
    data.append({
        'title':e.h3.text,
        'url':e.a.get('href'),
        'desc':e.next_sibling.text,
        'email': re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text).group(0) if 
re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text) else None
    })

data

title = print(title) # name error
desc = print(desc) # name error
email = print(email) # name error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue is that you try to reference only on `keys` without taking into account that there is `data` a list of dicts.

So you have to pick your dict by index from `data` if you like to print a specific one:

```
print(data[0]['title'])
print(data[0]['desc']) 
print(data[0]['email'])
```

Alternative just iterate over `data` and print/operate on the values of each dict:

```
for d in data:
    print(d['title'])
    print(d['desc']) 
    print(d['email'])
```

or

```
for d in data:
    title = d['title']
    desc = d['desc']
    email = d['email']
    
    print(f'print title only: {title}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that like this way:

```
for e in soup.select('div:has(> div > a h3)'):
    title=e.h3.text,
    url=e.a.get('href'),
    desc=e.next_sibling.text,
    email= re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text).group(0) if re.search(r'[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+\.[\w.-]+', e.parent.text) else None


    print(title)
    print(desc) 
    print(email)
    print(url)
```